# Defining a differential for use in a later differentiation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Suppose I have some function that I want to differentiate e.g. $f(t) = x(t)y(t)$.

I can do this in Mathematica as,

```
D[x*y, t, NonConstants -> {x, y}]
```

to obtain,

```
y D[x, t, NonConstants -> {x, y}] + x D[y, t, NonConstants -> {x, y}]
```

That's all fine. Now suppose I already independently **know** an expression for $y'(t)$. How can I replace the $y$ derivative,

```
D[y, t, NonConstants -> {x, y}]
```

with my known expression for $y'(t)$?

Comment: Something like `originalExpr /. HoldPattern[D[y, t, _]] :> expressionForDerivative`?

Comment: I would make all the functional dependencies explicit e.g. write `y[t]`